# ExifData gets saved but gallery image details are not updated

Tags: android, exif

I have an app in which I **visualize** metadata of some photos that I've taken and I can edit the location using a `Place Picker` and update the **exif** data using the following code:

```
                ExifInterface exifInterface = null;
                try {
                    exifInterface = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(exifInterface != null) {
                    try {

                        exifInterface.setLatLong(place.getLatLng().latitude,place.getLatLng().longitude);
                        exifInterface.saveAttributes();
                        sendBroadcastToUpdateMediaFile();
                        Log.v(TAG,"Updating with: "+place.getName());

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

The data does get the update because if I close the app and open it again and visualize the Exif data I can see the new **location** being there, but if I go inside the **gallery** and click details on the same image the location is not there. The photo format is **jpeg/jpg**, as only those types can have exif data(I get an error when trying to add **exifdata** on png for example).

Why is the exif data from the same image inside the gallery not get updated? What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Solution:

```
private void sendBroadcastToUpdateMediaFile(){
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Try using `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method to tell the `MediaStore` about the modified file, and see if that helps.

Comment: That indeed might be the case. I just checked if restarting the device would update the info, and it does. I will try using a broadcast.

Comment: @CommonsWare I edited with the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest that you answer your own question, rather than put the answer in the question itself. As it stands, it looks like this question has no answer. But I'm glad it is now working for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the MediaStore to get notified of the update you've just made on a photo, you have to use the `MediaScanner` to send a broadcast and scan the photo.

```
private void sendBroadcastToUpdateMediaFile(){
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            File f = new File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        }
```